# Passing Roles from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET CORE MVC to allow Authorize Attribute in Controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, claims

I think this is the first time to ask a question here, but wanted to try. Hope I got this right. I have searched all over web but nothing seems to come up for this scenario.

On a Test Project, I was going to have a ASP.NET Web API that will be exposed to the web. It will have authentication and authorization. The roles will be managed thru the Web API. I will have a ASP.NET CORE MVC app as one of the clients accessing the Web API.

What I would like to do is pass the users roles (in a Claim?) from the Web API into the Web Site and have the roles be used in the Controllers Authorize as well as in the views (menu filter and button disable functionality). Of course the issue is the separation of the Website from the Web API.

I have seen tutorials where the role is passed to a Angular/React/Vue site but I am trying to see about this in a Asp.net Core website.

I think I want to pass the claim(with the Roles) to the Website and have it use it as if the website was accessing the DB directly.

Just trying to figure out how this would be done.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how are you authenticating your web api ?

Comment: Could you show the codes related?

Comment: I have just been reading Web API tutorials. Not done any coding yet so I dont have any code to show.

Comment: I think you could read this document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Read it but did not give me what I wanted. Thanks though.

Comment: I think I found my solution. Instantiate the SignInManager after the response from the API that the user is authenticated and add the Roles Claim to the instantiation.  Then the Roles should be used in the Controller Authorize attribute.